# É uma má prática ter um parâmetro com mais de um tipo?

Tags: php, tipagem, parâmetros

É uma má prática ter um parâmetro com mais de um tipo?

Por exemplo, eu tenho um método que constrói uma classe com base em valores escalares:

```
public function of(int|string|float $value): Xpto
```

Se eu usar essa abordagem, seria melhor o próprio tipo `mixed` do PHP? Ou, na verdade, eu deveria ter um método diferente para cada tipo de parâmetro?

```
public function ofInt(int $value): Xpto

public function ofFloat(float $value): Xpto

public function ofString(string $value): Xpto
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depende.

PHP é uma linguagem de tipagem dinâmica. Toda biblioteca dela foi criada tendo isso em mente. Então se pensar que toda biblioteca de PHP tem uma má prática por aceitar qualquer tipo, e portanto usar PHP é uma má prática.

Se acha que usar PHP é uma boa prática então tem que considerar o que a linguagem sempre incentivou uma boa prática.

Se deseja programar em PHP do jeito novo e não se importar com as incoerências encontradas com todo código que não usa esse tipo de técnica de dizer qual é o tipo aceito, aí se torna uma má prática misturar tipos. Ou faz de um jeito ou faz de outro, quando adota as duas abordagens acaba que uma contamina a outra e tira sua vantagem. Boa sorte em adotar a tipagem estática em uma linguagem que nunca foi assim e tem toda a base de código, inclusive a biblioteca, com tipagem dinâmica.

Se quer ser mais estrito então criar os 3 métodos é o melhor, ainda mais se a implementação de cada um deles é diferente.

Só uma pena PHP não ter sobrecarga de métodos, então tem que anotar no nome do método o tipo que vai usar, o que deixar o código bem esquisito.

Se quer adotar esse jeito Java de programar então deve fazer sempre assim, consistência é fundamental. Mas se vai adotar isso porque não adotar Java? Ou C#? Ou outra linguagem que foi criada para ser assim?

Se a implementação é a mesma para os 3 tipos a opção de usar uma união de tipos em um só método pode ser bem adequada e muito mais simples. Só não vai fazer isso e dentro colocar um `if` ou algo equivalente para escolher o que fazer de acordo com o tipo que veio, aí é ruim sob vários pontos de vista. Essa forma tem a vantagem de só permitir esses 3 tipos, quanto mais restrição tem mais garantido fica.

Por último pode usar o `mixed` que é o padrão do PHP, assim perde a segurança de tipos e pode manipular qualquer dado que venha. Em poucos casos isso dará certo sem uma seleção do que fazer, pelo menos filtrar os tipos que podem não dar certo, afinal poucos algoritmos podem ser aplicados para absolutamente qualquer dado. Por exemplo se for só mandar imprimir algo com uma formatação bem universal é ok, mas se vai fazer uma conta não dará resultado adequado para quase todos os tipos existentes na linguagem.

Nunca ninguém morreu por usar essa forma não só em décadas usando PHP, mas também em diversas outras linguagens. É menos seguro, pode criar uma burocracia extra se quiser melhorar essa segurança, mas funciona quando o programador sabe o que está fazendo e é cuidadoso. O risco é maior, claro, mas é o preço que se paga por adotar uma linguagem de tipagem dinâmica.

Aí tenho que falar da "boa prática" como sempre faço. A maioria das pessoas entende que boa prática é uma regrinha ou conjunto delas que a pessoa deve seguir sempre e tudo ficará bom. Se for isso para você então já está fazendo errado, nunca fará uma boa prática. Se acha que fazer o certo em cada situação é o correto, não tem regra para seguir, precisa entender bem toda computação, todos os mecanismos das linguagens e tecnologias usadas, saber porque algo resolve ou causa problema, e aí tomar uma decisão, aí não é uma resposta no SOpt, uma artigo em um blog, muito menos um vídeo no Youtube que ensinará.

Também não adianta nada adotar a melhor forma para os parâmetros e dentro do método fazer tudo errado, por isso falei do `if`. Ninguém vai morrer se usar isso, só não faz sentido ter tanto trabalho e ser tão ineficiente se deseja dar mais garantias. Quem quer garantias deveria usar uma linguagem que as oferece nativamente, e de forma completa. Ou tem garantia ou não tem.

Dito isto, as pessoas estão cada vez mais adotando PHP como se ela fosse uma linguagem estática, mesmo sem ser. Se é o seu desejo, então faça sua escolha baseada na sua preferência. E arque com as consequências de cada uma delas todas opções tem vantagens e desvantagens, maiores ou menores de acordo com o caso concreto onde está sendo usado. Não canso de dizer que se é para fazer assim então deveria adotar uma linguagem que foi criada para trabalhar dessa forma.